# finding conditional variance in kyle model

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, conditional-variance

While desribing properties of the single auction equilibrium defined by theorem 1 in ["Continuous Auctions and Insider Trading"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1913210) A. Kyle conjectured that

> one-half of the insider's private information is incorporated into prices and
> the volatility of  prices is unaffected by the level  of  noise  trading $\sigma^2_u$.

Mathematically, the above conjecture is expressed in the text as the following formula: $$\Sigma_1 = \mathbf{var} \{v \mid x + u\} = \frac{1}{2}\Sigma_0 = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{var}\{{v}\} \tag{1} \label{one}$$
There $v$ denotes the *ex post* liquidation value ( a normal variable with mean $p_0$ and variance $\Sigma_0$)
$v\sim N(p_0,\Sigma_0)$

The insider define the size of its order $\tilde{x}$ **deterministically** as a function of the *ex post* liquidation value which he "observes" as an insider:

$$\label{three} x = \beta(v - p_0) \tag{2}$$

where $\beta=(\frac{\sigma_u^2}{\Sigma_0})^\frac{1}{2}$.

The volume of noise traders $u$ is a normally distributed random variable with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2_u$.

The model assumes that the insider and noise traders submit their market orders to the market maker who then sets the price at which  they  trade the  quantity necessary  to  clear the  market.

The total order flow $q = x+u = \beta(v - p_0)+u $ here v and u are jointly normal and also $v|q$ is normal

since $q = \beta(v - p_0)+u $ then:

$q\sim N(0,\beta^2 \Sigma_0+\sigma_u^2)$

$q|v\sim N(\beta(v-p_0),\sigma_u^2)$

then we can apply bayes rule to find the pdf of $v\mid q$ which is $ f(v\mid q) = f(v) \frac{f(q\mid v)}{f(q)} $

Substituting the parameters of the normal random variables we get $$  f(v\mid q) = \frac{K_1 K_2}{K_3} \exp\left[ \displaystyle-\left( \frac{(q-\beta(v-p_0))^2}{2\sigma_u^2} + \frac{(v-p_0)^2}{2\Sigma_0} \right) + \frac{q^2}{2(\beta^2 \Sigma_0+\sigma_u^2)} \right]$$

where $K1,K2,K3$ are density normalizing constants

from here can someone help me to find the variance of $v\mid q$? it should be $\left( \frac{1}{\Sigma_0}+\frac{\beta^2}{\sigma_u^2} \right)^{-1}$ , indeed from here substituting for $\beta$ and solving algebrically we get the desired result $\frac{1}{2} \Sigma_0$

Comment: Because $v$ manifestly has a Gaussian distribution, you can obtain the variance by inspection: simply express the log density as a quadratic function of $v;$ the variance is determined by the coefficient of $v^2.$  For more about this technique, please see our posts on [completing the square](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=complet*+square*)

Comment: i know that $f(v \mid q)$ is proportional to $f(v) f(q \mid v)$ . the posterior is normal with exponent equal to $\exp(\frac{(v-p_n)^2}{2 \Sigma_n})$;
$f(v) f(q \mid v)$ has the following exponent $$\exp(\frac{q-\beta(v-p_0))^2}{2 \sigma_u^2}+\frac{(v-p_0)^2}{2 \Sigma_0})$$
to find the inverse of the variance should I equate the 2 exponents considering only the $v^2$ term ? like this $\frac{v^2}{2\Sigma_n} = \frac{v^2}{2 \Sigma_0}+\frac{\beta^2 v^2}{2 \sigma_u^2}$  which is equal to $\frac{1}{\Sigma_n} = \frac{1}{\Sigma_0}+ \frac{\beta^2}{\sigma_u^2}$.

Comment: Of course,to find the variance $\Sigma_n$ we have simply to invert the term on the righ-hand side , that is, $\left( \frac{1}{\Sigma_0}+\frac{\beta^2}{\sigma_u^2} \right)^{-1}$ which is ,what I was trying to show . if my intuition is correct I should have derived the correct result

Comment: There's nothing to show: this is how Gaussian densities are characterized (their logarithms are quadratic forms).